# am I mocking httpBackend correctly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, httpbackend

Unit tests:

```
describe "Lunch controller", ->
  beforeEach module('Lunch')
  beforeEach inject(($httpBackend) ->
    $httpBackend.expectGET('/lunchers')
      .respond(200, ["some content", "some other content"])
  )

  describe "LunchCtrl", ->
    it "should set images to a populated array", inject(($controller, $httpBackend) ->
      scope = {}
      ctrl = $controller("LunchPoolController",
        $scope: scope
      )
      expect(scope.lunchers.length).toBe 2
    )
```

is throwing

```
 at /Users/jd/Dropbox/apps/lookingtolunch/spec/javascripts/controller_specs.js.coffee:13
INFO [watcher]: Changed file "/Users/jd/Dropbox/apps/lookingtolunch/spec/javascripts/controller_specs.js.coffee".
Chrome 32.0.1700 (Mac OS X 10.9.1) Lunch controller LunchCtrl should set images to a populated array FAILED
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
        at null.<anonymous> (/Users/jd/Dropbox/apps/lookingtolunch/spec/javascripts/controller_specs.js.js:13:35)
        at Object.invoke (http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js:7886:19)
        at workFn (http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js:14982:22)
    Error: Declaration Location
        at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (http://localhost:3000/assets/application.js:14970:27)
        at null.<anonymous> (/Users/jd/Dropbox/apps/lookingtolunch/spec/javascripts/controller_specs.js.js:7:57)
        at null.<anonymous> (/Users/jd/Dropbox/apps/lookingtolunch/spec/javascripts/controller_specs.js.js:6:10)
        at /Users/jd/Dropbox/apps/lookingtolunch/spec/javascripts/controller_specs.js.js:1:1
Chrome 32.0.1700 (Mac OS X 10.9.1): Executed 2 of 2 (1 FAILED) (2.766 secs / 0.201 secs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `LunchPoolController` is firing off an HTTP request, you'll need to use `$httpBackend.flush()` to make sure all requests are going through.  (For more, see the [Flushing HTTP requests](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.%24httpBackend)
 section).

Comment: actually, that controller has a service injected into it, so maybe the issue is that I'm not injecting the service into the controller in these specs ?